# Spring - Conflict when using property expansion (processResources) and use properties references in application.yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

Environment:
- Spring boot
- Gradle
- Kotlin

I was configure the Automatic Property Expansion in Gradle to use gradle properties in my application.yml

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("application.yml") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

It's work perfectly when I don't use properties references in the same application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 123

application:
  version: ${version}
```

But, when I use properties references in the application.yml like this :

```
server:
  port: 123

application:
  version: ${version}

foo:
  bar: ${server.port}
```

Occurs that problem in compilation:

*** No such property: server for class: SimpleTemplateScript23 ***

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':application:configuration:processResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy file '/home/gbzarelli/Documents/github/java/klean-arch-sample/application/configuration/src/main/resources/application.yml' to '/home/gbzarelli/Documents/github/java/klean-arch-sample/application/configuration/build/resources/main/application.yml'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:698)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:700)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:499)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:179)
    at org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.copy(ProcessResources.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor943.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:401)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:390)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:373)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:210)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: server for class: SimpleTemplateScript23
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
    at SimpleTemplateScript23.run(SimpleTemplateScript23.groovy:1)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.writeTo(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:181)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.ChainingTransformer.transform(ChainingTransformer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.open(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
    ... 125 more
```

In this case the application file in `build/resources` is empty, I believe that has a conflict or a properties references replacement  when I use the extension `proccessResources`, I didn't find any references in the `Spring` documentations about it. I found one references in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Answer (score 7):

Solution:

The Gradle expand ${..} style conflicts with the same Spring property placeholder style and therefor needs to be escaped like \${..}. This is added to Spring Boot docs now:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/c0c67f2593dbfd17aa304b43f4da3a3678fa58eb

The escape must be add in your property reference, like this:

```
server:
  port: 123

application:
  version: ${version}

foo:
  bar: \${server.port}
```